# How to change the angle of the end of a canvas arc?

Tags: html, html5-canvas, kineticjs, fabricjs, paperjs

I`m trying to build what my designer designed in photoshop with Kinetic (but willing to use some other library). This is what my designer designed:

http://d.pr/i/upJd

Seems no rocket science just some arcs and circles. But the end of the arcs are not in line with the circle but vertical. I`ve been trying and trying but no luck so far. Anybody have an idea?

My code:

```
  var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 578,
    height: 400
  });

  var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

    var circle = new Kinetic.Circle({
    x: stage.getWidth() / 2,
    y: stage.getHeight() / 2,
    radius: 169,
    fill: '#C0210F'
   // stroke: 'black',
   // strokeWidth: 4
  });

  var wedge = new Kinetic.Wedge({
    x: stage.getWidth() / 2,
    y: stage.getHeight() / 2,
    radius: 170,
    angleDeg: 200,
    fill: '#EFC8C3',
    //stroke: 'black',
    //strokeWidth: 4,
    rotationDeg: -90
  });

    var circle2 = new Kinetic.Circle({
    x: stage.getWidth() / 2,
    y: stage.getHeight() / 2,
    radius: 120,
    fill: '#c02428'
    //stroke: 'black',
    //strokeWidth: 4
  });

  var wedge2 = new Kinetic.Wedge({
    x: stage.getWidth() / 2,
    y: stage.getHeight() / 2,
    radius: 120,
    angleDeg: 220,
    fill: '#611B61',
    //stroke: 'black',
    //strokeWidth: 4,
    rotationDeg: -90
  });

  var circle3 = new Kinetic.Circle({
    x: stage.getWidth() / 2,
    y: stage.getHeight() / 2,
    radius: 110,
    fill: 'red'
    //stroke: 'black',
    //strokeWidth: 4
  });

  // add the shape to the layer
  layer.add(circle);
  layer.add(wedge);
  layer.add(circle2);
  layer.add(wedge2);
  layer.add(circle3);

  // add the layer to the stage
  stage.add(layer);
```

fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/ExwER/

Kind Regards,

Peter

Comment: Punch your designer ;) You could do it with a couple mask to hide the end of the arc when its drawn, but otherwise a circle simply wont work like that.

Comment: Look into http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-clipping-functions-with-kineticjs/

Comment: Thanks eric but my designer is a bigger guy than I am ;) Goining to try and clip the stuff ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Kinetic.Shape to stroke actual Arcs instead of hiding hiding or clipping shapes.

With Kinetic.Shape, you get access to a real canvas context so you can draw the arcs your designer has given you--resulting in simpler coding for you ;)

[image]

Here is code to make multiple donut charts and a demo Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/9uHD7/

```
function makeChart(x,y,percent){
    var PI=Math.PI;
    var startAngle=-PI/2;
    var endAngle=2*PI*percent/100-PI/2;
    var cx=width/2;
    var cy=height/2;

    var arcChart=new Kinetic.Group({
        x:x,
        y:y,
        width:width,
        height:height
    });
    layer.add(arcChart);

    var fullArc = new Kinetic.Shape({
      drawFunc: function(context) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(cx,cy,radius,0,Math.PI*2,false);
        context.closePath();
        context.fillStrokeShape(this);
      },
      stroke: 'rgb(153,0,0)',
      strokeWidth: outerStrokeWidth
    });
    arcChart.add(fullArc);

    var outerArc = new Kinetic.Shape({
      drawFunc: function(context) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(cx,cy,radius,startAngle,endAngle,false);
        context.fillStrokeShape(this);
      },
      stroke: 'lightgray',
      strokeWidth: outerStrokeWidth
    });
    arcChart.add(outerArc);

    var innerArc = new Kinetic.Shape({
      drawFunc: function(context) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(cx,cy,this.radius,startAngle,endAngle,false);
        context.fillStrokeShape(this);
      },
      stroke: 'purple',
      strokeWidth: innerStrokeWidth
    });
    // calc the inner radius
    innerArc.radius=radius-outerStrokeWidth/2+innerStrokeWidth/2;
    arcChart.add(innerArc);

}
```

Comment: Thanks markE! The arcs also need to animate.. so the white bar will grow bigger or smaller... same goes for the purple one...  so drawing is one but it needs to be variable....

Comment: Hi mark, Thanks for some Kinetic lessons.. good to see that it is this powerfull.. what I needed was to make the end of the arc clipped like my designer did... after your and post of others I created this: http://jsfiddle.net/xember/HB4YA/2/ Nice for this position but when it goes to `nine O clock´ it doesn`t make sense to cut the shape like this.... need to talk to the desiner... BUT learned a lot! Thanks!

Comment: I think like @ericjbasti does: Your designer couldn't make the purple and white arcs end at the same spot.  Suggestion: don't try to recreate their design, instead--make it right!

Comment: Yeah I know but the purple and white arcs represent some different things.. thas why they are not ending at the same spot.... think we need a new design for this ;) Thanks again for your help!

Comment: COOL!!!! That`s really great! I need my designer look at this! Do you program this stuff for a living?

Comment: I program accounting solutions for a living.  I just use html canvas & svg to make business information interesting for users.

Comment: Ah ok. Well I just started programming canvas so what you deliver in 20 minutes will cost me half a day ;)